# ROUND() function doesn't work with OVER clause

Tags: mysql, rounding, over-clause

The code below doesn't work when I replace SUM(Sales) with `ROUND(SUM(Sales),2)`, works otherwise. Sales field type = Double.

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Region) as Row_No, Name as Product, Category, Sales,
SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY Region, Category) as Category_Sales,
SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY Region) as Regional_Sales
FROM table
WHERE Region = "North"
ORDER BY Category, Sales;
```

**Error** thrown (MySQL 8) : OVER is not valid at this position, expecting ';'
Tried using CONVERT() and CAST() to convert the aggregate values to INT. Didn't work either. That said, ROUND() works fine without OVER clause as in the code below.

```
SELECT Region, Category, ROUND(SUM(Sales),2) as Total_Sales
FROM table
GROUP BY Category;
```

**What's going on and how do I make this work so that aggregate sales values are rounded to d decimals using ROUND(Val, d) alongwith the OVER clause?**

Comment: I would imaging Round has to be over the whole window function..eg round(SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY Region, Category),2) as Category_Sales

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon! That fixed it.  I am still not clear as to why it won't work when I try to round just the aggregate values before applying the window function?

Comment: In a window function the sum is over... ,sum is not executed then window function applied